# HTML5 video sprites

Tags: javascript, html5, synchronization, media

I'm currently working on a project where there is a requirement to dynamically composite multiple synchronised video sources onto a single canvas. The initial prototype I put together loaded the video into HTMLVideoElements and then used requestAnimFrame (via [Paul Irish's shim](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)) to draw these onto a single canvas and maintain sync between the different elements.

Although this is functional and the system can hold sync fairly well (+/- 80ms tolerance) it is somewhat inefficient to say the least. I've been thinking about optimisations and one approach that seems pretty straight forward is to combine all the media into a single larger 'video sprite' and serve this. This would allow it to be load into a single video element which could then be used extract and render the areas of interest client side using `drawImage()` and remove the need to manage sync between sources.

Has anyone else implemented something similar in the past? If so what approach worked well for you?

Comment: +1 for probably the best personal website on Programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out popcorn.js?

Popcorn.js is an HTML5 media framework written in JavaScript for filmmakers, web developers, and anyone who wants to create time-based interactive media on the web. Popcorn.js is part of Mozilla's Popcorn project.

http://popcornjs.org/

Comment: Yep, all over popcorn. Unfortunately however it addresses a different set of issues. The challenge faced in this project was to do with maintaining sync between a set of dynamically selectable media resources.